# Sorting and Matching a Python list

Tags: python, list, sorting, collections, defaultdict

I recently asked a similar question but need to go a little deeper.

Essentially, I am reading a directory of files and appending everything to a list called **filelistname**

I am trying to sort this list by the **diskcount** (-#disk-), and running a function against that sorted list.

Thanks for your help.

---

Here is an example -

```
 In []: filelistname
Out []: ['C:\Test3\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx'
         'C:\Test1\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-17disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\Test4\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\Test2\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-18disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\Test1\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\Test6\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\Test2\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-0-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\Test5\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-100-segmented.xlsx']
```

An output for this would look something like this.

*A group*

```
  C:\Test3\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx
  C:\Test1\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-17disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx
  C:\Test2\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-18disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx
```

*Another gorup*

```
  C:\Test4\ARRAY05-4NODE-RAID1-25disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx
```

*Another group*

```
  C:\Test1\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx
  C:\Test6\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx
```

*Another Group*

```
  C:\Test2\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-0-segmented.xlsx
```

*Another group*

```
  C:\Test5\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-100-segmented.xlsx
```

---

I'm currently playing with this, but having trouble identifying a correct key.

```
import os
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

key_fn = lambda s: s.rsplit('-',4)[0]

filelistname = sorted(filelistname, key=key_fn)
print(key)

for key, grouped_file_names in groupby(filelistname, key=key_fn):
    print('\n'.join(list(grouped_file_names)))
    print("")
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @whrrgarbl I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be grouping by  `d+k-d+` so split the basename and use those as the keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for sub in l:
    spl = sub.rsplit("-", 3)
    k = spl[-3],spl[-2]
    d[k].append(sub)
```

Output:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(d)

{ ('128k', '0'): [ 'C:\\Test3\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsxC:\\Test1\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-17disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                   'C:\\Test4\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                   'C:\\Test2\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-18disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx'],
  ('32k', '0'): [ 'C:\\Test1\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                  'C:\\Test6\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx'],
  ('64k', '0'): ['C:\\Test2\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-0-segmented.xlsx'],
  ('64k', '100'): [ 'C:\\Test5\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-100-segmented.xlsx']}
```

If you want all but the disk part:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from os import path
from ntpath import basename
d = defaultdict(list)

for sub in l:
    spl = basename(sub).rsplit("-", 5)
    k = spl[0]+"-" + "-".join(spl[3:5])
    d[k].append(sub)
```

Output:

```
{'ARRAY05-2NODE-128k-0': ['C:\\Test3\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                          'C:\\Test1\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-17disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                          'C:\\Test4\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                          'C:\\Test2\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-18disk-128k-0-segmented.xlsx'],
 'ARRAY05-2NODE-32k-0': ['C:\\Test1\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx',
                         'C:\\Test6\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-25disk-32k-0-segmented.xlsx'],
 'ARRAY05-2NODE-64k-0': ['C:\\Test2\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-0-segmented.xlsx'],
 'ARRAY05-2NODE-64k-100': ['C:\\Test5\\ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-100-segmented.xlsx']}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! How can I include the sorting to include the first 3 elements as well such as "ARRAY#, NODE, RAID". Basically sort with everything before the #diskcount as well. I tried using k = spl[-2],spl[-3],spl[-4]

Comment: @user2877133, are you wanting to sort or group?

Comment: I guess it would be considered grouping? Order does not matter.

Comment: So basically you want to  remove `12disk` and keep the rest from `ARRAY05-2NODE-RAID1-12disk-64k-100`?

Comment: Yes, group by everything except the diskcount. Let me update my example.